# Django: Overriding the Save (Either Model or Admin Section)

Tags: python, sql, django, save, models

I've been playing around with Django recently, however I'm stuck on how to approach this problem. I have a 'Person' model which has a one to many relationship with a 'Voucher' Model. Now the person has a quota and each time a Voucher is generated, the quota will decrease by one. What I'm stuck on is doing this through the save method. So how does one do this?

Below are my models:

```
class Person(AbstractDetail):
# Note: Model to maintain information about Person
     vc = models.IntegerField(default = 3, verbose_name = 'Vouchers', 
     null = False, validators = [ validate_voucher ])

class Voucher(models.Model):
# Note: Model to maintain information about Voucher
     vc = models.CharField (max_length = 25, verbose_name = 'Voucher ID',
                     help_text = 'Voucher Identifier')
     ps = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete = models.CASCADE,
                       verbose_name = 'Person')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it in `save()`, it's easily messed up with django. Try to use django signal `post_save()`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Voucher)
def decrease_quota(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.vc -= 1
        instance.save()
```

Check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/) for django signals.

Comment: It not working yet, but you put me to the right direction now so I thank you for that, If I get it working then post up the code as well. I upvote your answer as it show other where to go from here on

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a slight performance hit in favour of avoiding the duplication of the voucher count information (call me old-fashioned).

In stead of saving the voucher count in Person.vc, I'd evaluate the voucher count when needed by creating a function for that in the Voucher object manager:

```
def get_voucher_count(self, person):
    return self.filter(ps=person).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I manage to work it out (with the help of Shang Wang & Ytsen de Boer answer as well, which I'm grateful for). The way which I did it was to create an instance of the object `Person` and take away from it there.

Fortunately enough, I quick time check the doc's which Shang just showed me (and look way deeper as well). Below is the way to do it:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Voucher, dispatch_uid = "voucher_identifier")
def decrease_quota(sender, instance, **kwargs):
obj = Person.objects.get(pk = instance.ps.id)
if obj.vc < 4 and obj.vc > 0:
    obj.vc = obj.vc - 1
    obj.save()
```

Of course I have to do abit more to it (simple validations and stuff like that), but this how I needed it.